# Arduino self shutdown using relay not working

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a project that need to shutdown arduino main power (not sleep) to save battery.
Follow this tutorial:
[zola lab](https://www.zolalab.com.br/eletronica_projetos/auto_shutdown_enus.php)

Here is Zola scheme (i choose the relay option):

[image]

And here what i have done:
[image]

The code:

```
//  www.zolalab.com.br  -  By Eduardo Zola  -  2016


void setup() 
{
   pinMode(7,OUTPUT);    // Relay Signal Pin
   digitalWrite(7,HIGH);

   pinMode(8,OUTPUT);     // buzzer & LED  (start with buzzer on)
   digitalWrite(8,HIGH);  

   pinMode(13,OUTPUT);   // LED built-in Arduino
   digitalWrite(13,HIGH);

   delay(50);           
   digitalWrite(8,LOW);   // turn off buzzer


   delay(5000);   // wait for 5 seconds to shutdown the circuit


   for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);delay(80);digitalWrite(8,LOW);delay(600);
   };   // beeps
   digitalWrite(8,HIGH);delay(1000);digitalWrite(8,LOW);

   digitalWrite(7,LOW);  // shutdown the circuit

}

void loop() 
{

}
```

My main power 5v in breadboard come at the top left.

The relay is different. My relay is this:
[image]

Problem is, when i click switch button in the breadboard, nothing happened.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What should happen? Arduino should start after a button press, and shutdown itself after 5 seconds? Are you sure you have jumper on relay module set correctly? Have you checked all connections?

Comment: Yes after 5 seconds will shutdown itself. I'm not expert and not sure about the jumper. That jumper position is factory default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
Change the `digitalWrite` from `HIGH` to `LOW` and `LOW` to `HIGH` for pin 7

```
void setup() 
{
    pinMode(7,OUTPUT);    // Relay Signal Pin
    digitalWrite(7,LOW); // <-- change this

    ...
    ...

    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);  // shutdown the circuit <-- change this too
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

Hope this help others for having same relay.

Answer (score 1):

The breadboards like yours usually have power rails separated in the middle. On a photo of your setup it looks like you connected your power supply to the upper half of the board, and reset of the circuit to the lower. Try connecting everything on the same half, or use jumpers to connect power rails.

Comment: I put that way to make me easier to see. I know that have separated power rail. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Forget to mention, i use the jumper already, as in relays product photo. Mine is black instead of yellow. JD-VCC to VCC. (Factory default). I did not change it.